# Parse::RecDescent and Grammar

Tags: perl, parse-recdescent

I defined the following grammar using Parse::RecDescent

```
my $grammar = q{

top : operand equal value { print $item{value} }

operand: /\w+/     

equal : /\=/

value : { my $value = extract_quotelike($text) ;$return =$value;} 

};
```

which i wants it to handle the following cases :

X = 2 -> should print 2

X = "2" -> should print 2

x = '2' -> should print 2

but the above grammar provide different results :

for x=2 it fail to parse it

for x="2" -> it print "2"

for x ='2' -> it pring '2'

any idea to change the above grammar to print 2 on all the the 3 above cases , i.e removing the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build_parser.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::RecDescent qw( );

Parse::RecDescent->Precompile(<<'__EOS__', "Parser");
   {
      # The code in rules is also covered by these pragmas.
      use strict;
      use warnings;

      sub dequote { substr($_[0], 1, -1) =~ s/\\(.)/$1/srg }
   }

   start     : assign /\Z/ { $item[1] }

   assign    : lvalue '=' expr { [ 'assign', $item[1], $item[3] ] }

   lvalue    : IDENT

   expr      : NUM_LIT { [ 'num_const', $item[1] ] }
             | STR_LIT { [ 'str_const', $item[1] ] }

   # TOKENS
   # ----------------------------------------

   IDENT     : \w+

   NUM_LIT   : /[0-9]+/

   STR_LIT   : /'(?:[^'\\]++|\\.)*+'/s { dequote($item[1]) }
             | /"(?:[^"\\]++|\\.)*+"/s { dequote($item[1]) }

__EOS__
```

Adjust the definition of string literals to your needs (but remember to adjust both the rule and `dequote`).

Running `build_parser.pl` will generate `Parser.pm`, which can be used as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
use Parser       qw( );

my $parser = Parser->new();
print(Dumper( $parser->start('x = 2') ));
```